# How to use Pygame with PyCharm on Windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, pycharm

I use PyCharm on Windows with Python 2.7 interpreter. I'd like to write a GUI using pygame. So I downloaded the package pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi  from the website: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

However, when I try running the following code:

```
from pygame.locals import *
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
```

The pygame package is still unrecognized - it is underlined as an error. However, it is visible as an installed package in the settings.

How can I fix it?

Edit1: `import pygame` doesn't help.

Here is the error:

*WARNING:root:No virtualenv active
  File "C:/Users/User/Python/Project/Game/main.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa0' in file C:/Users/User/Python/Project/Game/main.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details*

Comment: You have Non_ASCII character '\xa0'  in first line in `main.py`. Maybe it is native character.

Comment: No, I copied the code I have.  I looked it up - this non ASCII character is a non- breaking space in  ISO 8859-1. OK, I'll try replacing all spaces I have with "normal" spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
import pygame
```

instead

```
import pygame.locals import *
```

Or show the error